# Find all positive integers $a$ for which there exists some positive integer $b$ s.t. $(2^a-1)\mid(b^2+9)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $a$ for which there exists some positive integer $b$ s.t.

$(2^a-1)\mid(b^2+9)$

Comment: Welcome to SE. It would be helpful if you explain what you tried so far and where you got stuck. This will help you get better answers to your question.

Comment: This is an old question from an IMO Shortlist (1998?).

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, I'll limit myself to some hints.

First, handle the cases $a=1$ and $a=2$.

Then, for $a\gt2$, consider prime divisors congruent $3$ mod $4$ of $2^a-1$ and of $b^2+9$.

Answer (score 0):

**LEMMA.** If $p=4k+3$ is a prime such that $p|a^2+b^2$ for any integer numbers $a,b$ then $p|a,p|b$.

*Proof.* If at least one of two numbers $a,b$ is divisible by $p$ then the other is also divisible by $p$.

If $p \nmid a,p \nmid b$ then by Fermat's Little Theorem we have $a^{p-1}=a^{4k+2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $b^{p-1} =b^{4k+2} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Hence $a^{4k+2}+b^{4k+2} \equiv 2 \pmod{p}$. But $p|a^2+b^2| a^{4k+2}+b^{4k+2}$ then $p=2$, a contradiction.

Thus, $p|a,p|b$.

**SOLUTION.** Let $a=2^k \cdot l$ with $k,l \in \mathbb{N}$ and $2 \nmid l$. It is to see that $a=1,2$ is a solution. If $a \ge 3$.

We have $2^a-1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ then it is always exist a prime $p=4k+3$ is a divisor of $2^a-1$. Hence $p|b^2+9$. We get $p|3$ by the lemma. Thus, $p=3$.

If $l \ge 3$ then $2^l-1|2^a-1$. We also have $2^l-1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. It follows that $2^l-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$,a contradiction since $l$ is odd.

Thus, $l=1$. We get $a$ is a power of $2$.